# How to set some weights in a layer to a particulr number?

Tags: neural-network, caffe, pycaffe, weighted-average, matcaffe

I would like to ask if  it is possible to set some weights in a layer to particular number or zero of pretrained model.

For example, I want to download Lecun model and set some weights in the last layer to number e.x `4` and calculate the accuracy.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are after ["net surgery"](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb). In python you can load the net and get direct access to the stored weights. Then you can tweak them as you pleased and save the modified net.

Comment: Many thanks, is there any example to do so and access to a particular weight in a layer as I am new in programming.

Comment: @S.AMEEN please go through the "net surgery" notebook tutorial I linked to in the answer. It contains examples of setting filter weights to specific values (near `In [4]`, and `In [5]`).